# Splitting strings with record options

Tags: fortran

I have a string with record options from a db, for example:

```
str = "-t Maintainer -e Name = Luca"
```

How can I separate the string of record options so I have two arrays as follows. I want this to work for any set the record options using `-key value` or `--key value`.

```
key(i) = ["t", "e"]
val(i) = ["Maintainer", "Name = Luca"]
```

I would also want to split the strings to separate strings according to the criteria.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: It took me one minute to find [this in the Fortran Wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Command-line+arguments). Especially, [this link](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/getopt_long_module) from the list provides what you are looking for. Did you do any research for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Fortran has a function named `index` that gives the index of beginning of the first or last occurrence of a substring in a given string. You can use that function to get what you want, bellow is an example extracting from the last occurrence.

Here is a starting point:

```
program test
implicit none

    character(*), parameter :: str = "-t Maintainer -e Name = Luca"
    integer pos1, pos2

    pos2 = index(str, '-', .true.)
    print*, "key2 = ", str(pos2+1:pos2+1)
    print*, "val2 = ", adjustl( str(pos2+2:) )

    pos1 = index(str(:pos2-1), '-', .true.)
    print*, "key1 = ", str(pos1+1:pos1+1)
    print*, "val1 = ", adjustl( str(pos1+2:pos2-1) )

end
```

outputs

```
key2 = e
val2 = Name = Luca
key1 = t
val1 = Maintainer
```

You can adapt to your needs

Comment: I might have long options in this, for example `--rec-type Maintainer` so I really need to split on spaces not just `-`.

Comment: the second parameter of index if also a string, so it can be whatever.

Comment: In addition @Zeus, the ultimate goal is not to solve your problem in details but to give you hints and pointers for the solution.

Comment: I might split on a space and then check for `-` or `--` at the beginning

Comment: @Zeus, did this help solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help, please let me know so that I can delete it to save people from wasting their time looking at it.